# Simple LINQ and/or query condition clarification

Tags: c#, linq

This is a very simple LINQ and/or question.

In the following query excerpt, my intention is to obtain records which match any of the three conditions below.

Is my logic correct or is there a better way to phrase this?

- (t2.Username == userName) && (viewMode == 1)
- (t1.Owner == userName) && (viewMode == 1)
- (viewMode == 2)

**Query excerpt**

```
where
((t2.Username == userName) && (viewMode == 1)) ||
((t1.Owner == userName) && (viewMode == 1)) || 
((viewMode == 2))
```

Comment: Seems like this would be much better suited for a unit test since this is either a "it works or it doesn't" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logic looks fine, you could of course do it slightly differently:

```
where ( (viewMode == 1 && ( t2.Username == userName || t1.Owner == userName ))
   || viewMode == 2)
```

Whichever looks better to your eyes I guess!

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the same result a little more efficiently:

```
viewMode == 2 ||
(viewMode == 1 && (t2.Username == userName || t1.Owner == userName))
```